# Exchange file in image with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I'm using a docker image `arm64v8/postgres:14.0-alpine` which works perfectly well on my local Pi4, but I would like to change the pg_hba.conf (changing some IP settings). My docker-compose file (extract) looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgres:
      image: arm64v8/postgres:14.0-alpine
      volumes:
        - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment: 
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
        - POSTGRES_DB=xxx
        - POSTGRES_USER=xxx
      networks:
      - manager

volumes:
  database:

networks:
  manager:
    driver: bridge
```

Everything works fine, but now I would like docker-compose to switch the `pg_hba.conf` file under `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`for the `pg_hba.conf` in my local directory (same as docker-compose file). When the container restarts this should be contained.

If there is a better solution please let me know. I would like to avoid building my own images.

Thanks

Comment: What is preventing you from adding a volume for that file?

Comment: Never done it before :-). How do I define that one file via a volume and make sure that it is overwritten? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you are looking for this

```
  volumes:
    - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ./pg_hba.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf:ro
```

However, you might run into an issue with having the docker volume mount and file mounted at the same location, so the other solution is to use `docker cp` command to copy the file into the mounted location after the container has started, which should persist it as part of the volume.

You could also not use a volume, then just have the files mounted as a regular folder on your local machine, which you could edit

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way. Created a Dockerfile with the image and used  `Copy` to copy my modified file.

```
FROM arm64v8/postgres:14.0-alpine
COPY ./pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/
```